# Are misaligned data types stored and retrieved properly on ARM based systems?

Tags: c, arm, memory-alignment

I have an array of `int16_t` which holds instructions for a virtual machine.  However, to store constants, the array will have some larger data types in there as well, up to doubles.  I have tried this to store and retrieve misaligned doubles, and it seems to work on desktop:

```
int16_t instructionMemory[SIZE];
int16_t* ptr = instructionMemory + 1;  // Offset by 16 bits
*((double*)ptr) = 3.14;                // Store

printf("%lf", *((double*)ptr));        // Retrieve
```

However, I have read that whether or not misaligned data types work or not is architecture-dependent.  Will the above work on ARM-based chips?  The alternative to this would be to do some manual bit shifting and OR-ing I imagine.

Comment: It depends on your architecture version, and how your OS has chosen to configure the CPU.  See https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/using-the-assembler/address-alignment for ARMv7 and earlier.

Comment: The simplest alternative is usually `memcpy` which the compiler will easily optimize out on systems that don't need it.  `double d = 3.14; memcpy(instructionMemory+1, &d, sizeof(double));`.  Your approach via "type punning" is not safe at the compiler level, since it violates the strict aliasing rule.